# How to address having been plagiarized by senior scholars without ruining the relationship

Tags: plagiarism, communication

I recently came across a book written by two senior scholars in my field (anthropology), who cite a paper I published with a colleague two years ago.  They cite us quite favorably and in most places they cite us correctly. However, there are two passages which they have copied verbatim from our paper but without attributing them to us, nor even citing us anywhere on the respective pages.

What should we do about that?  We certainly don't want to ruin our relationship.
What are appropriate steps to be taken?

We have never met the authors in person but been exchanging emails with one of them a few times – all very positive exchanges. He is also supposed to participate in a conference panel with us this year. How to bring it up and what should we expect from them to do?

Comment: How large are the passages?

Comment: Which field are you in? Which parts of the paper did they copy verbatim? Plagiarism standards vary considerably between different fields.

Comment: Could this be an honest mistake?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It is difficult to say if this was intentional or only an oversight - though an improper one. But the fact that they cite you generally, seems to imply sloppiness, not malice. Ask for a correction.

I would simply point out the passages to them and provide them a proper citation for them. Since this is a book, it will likely go through several printings and it may be possible for the future printings to be corrected. Published books often come with an errata page, usually online these days.

You don't need to make accusations, just point out the correction.

If you get a poor response from the authors, then try to contact the publisher, starting with just the same information and request.

But if you get a favorable response, then thank them and, if you desire, say positive things about their work and point again to your own. From a bad situation it might turn in to a good one. But that assumes good will.

Comment: Adding to this: If you can bundle this together with a few other errata to make clear that you are genuinely interested in improving the book rather than more selfish motivations.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft, good suggestion. Some authors (or at least Don Knuth) actually pay people for reporting errors. Oddly, though, people who get a small check from him tend not to cash it, but to frame it on their wall. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth_reward_check

Comment: Well, if all academics reacted to errata like this, we wouldn’t need this question.

Comment: The OP's message to the book's authors could begin by thanking them for the favorable citations, and then pointing out that citations were apparently overlooked in a couple of places.

Comment: Copying verbatim cannot be an oversight.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanlon%27s_razor You just need to imagine being interrupted. You copy something, the doorbell rings, you go open the door, accept the package, go back to the desk and by the time you get back you are already thinking about the next parts of the paper and continue without ever adding the citation. Is it sloppy? Yes, something slipped your mind. Was it intentional? No. Should the culprit be more careful? Definitely. But that doesn't make it intentional or malice.

Comment: @AndreasBlass  Yes, I think that's what I'm going to do.  It does look like an oversight.

Comment: @Polygnome also psychologically, some people simply consider text attribution way less important than idea attribution. They might care less about their own texts and they might also not be as careful when attributing text sources. Not saying they shouldn't, just explaining why someone can easily be good and rigorous in some way and a bit sloppy in another without intended malice (e.g. simply because they would not feel affected if someone "did it to them").

Comment: @Wrzlprmft  This is a great idea.  Actually, there are plenty of errors.  I'm always baffled by how sloppy some established scholars can be.  In fact, one of the rather funny errors introduced by them copying us was that the copied passage included references to other scholars works.  They did look those up but only by name and year and for one of those, in the bibliography they cited a different paper that that person had published in the same year.  Which has nothing to do wiith the argument being made.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist to back up Polygnome's point, I've often had to tell my students not to paste text in the first place, as doing so sets you up for this sort of thing.  It's far better to put a few words of summary about what you're trying to write

Comment: @Polygnome No, forgetting to add a citation does not excuse copying verbatim.  It would still be plagiarism even if there was a citation.

Comment: @ChrisH It sounds like you agree with me; if this was a "mistake" it was deliberately set up by breaking the practice of never copying.

Comment: @ChrisH Another good habit is to put quotation marks first, then pasting between them. Even if you somehow get distracted and forget the citation, the quotation marks show that it is quoted from *somewhere* and it should raise a flag during review so you can go back and add the missing citation.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist I'm not saying it isn't. Obviously if you copy verbatim you would also need quotation marks. My point was that yes, this can happen by mistake. And if it happens very rarely, one should assume a mistake. Humans are fallible (except you, I presume?) and do make mistakes. If it happens more then very rarely, one should be wary, though. But OP was already cited multiple times, which means the authors do not seem to want to deceive. I do not see what you have to gain from accusing them of malice. If you want the error corrected, give 'em the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: Actually plagiarism is avoided with a citation. There may be other offenses, of course, but not plagiarism. Of course it needs to be clear what you are citing.

Answer (score 10):

I have had my own work plagiarized and I know it does not feel good, in fact I was quite upset when it happened. In that case the plagiarism was pretty extensive and clearly done with malicious intent (by a graduate student at another institution), and I acted to inform the relevant people. I also had a mild concern at the time that the timeline of events might lead others to conclude erroneously that it was me who plagiarized from the student rather than the other way around.

In your case, however, it sounds like the incident is really too trivial to risk hurting your good relationship with these researchers over. In a comment you say the book contains many errors and there are obvious signs that this was nothing more than sloppiness on the part of the authors. And it sounds like there is no concern you will be mistaken as the plagiarist. So it’s not clear to me what exactly there is to be gained from correcting the mistake in a practical sense, other than to address your own feeling of injustice (which as I said I completely understand and absolutely do not mean to belittle). I assume that these two passages consist of ordinary, everyday text rather than some masterpiece of human ingenuity that will be remembered for many centuries.

My suggestion is to leave it to readers of the book to draw their own conclusions about the professionalism of these authors. If the sloppiness is that obvious, I doubt anyone will be too surprised or shocked to find two unattributed passages in addition to all the other errors. And it is generally not your responsibility to help sloppy scholars improve their work. So, as much as it may be emotionally difficult to do, the best course of action may be simply to do nothing.

Answer (score -8):

Since you do not supervise these senior scholars and you did not coauthor the plagiarism, you are under no obligation to do anything.